# ; Expected in java netbeans , how can i fix it ??

Tags: java, netbeans

; Exptected

```
String sql= "INSERT INTO tbl_iklan VALUES ('"+txt_nama.getText()+"','"+txt_jenis.getText()+"','"+txt_warna.getText()"','"+txt_ukuran.getText()+"','"+txt_halaman.getText()+"')";
```

Comment: likely you've forgotten an + somewhere in your String concatenation

Comment: String sql= "INSERT INTO tbl_iklan VALUES ('"+txt_nama.getText()+"','"+txt_jenis.getText()+"','"+txt_warna.getText()"','"+txt_ukuran.getText()+"','"+txt_halaman.getText()+"')";

how about this ?? i think this okay but this error give me a message " ; not exptected not a statement

Comment: you forgot a + after  txt_warna.getText()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected, you forgot a `+` in your `String` concatenation.

Replace

```
String sql= "INSERT INTO tbl_iklan VALUES ('"+txt_nama.getText()+"','"+txt_jenis.getText()+"','"+txt_warna.getText()"','"+txt_ukuran.getText()+"','"+txt_halaman.getText()+"')";
```

by

```
String sql= "INSERT INTO tbl_iklan VALUES ('"+txt_nama.getText()+"','"+txt_jenis.getText()+"','"+txt_warna.getText() + "','"+txt_ukuran.getText()+"','"+txt_halaman.getText()+"')";
```

Comment: thannk your sir